# Removal of object from realm Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x288 in tid 29635

Tags: realm

I am trying to remove just one object from Realm. But I keep failing. I try to update the record and see at the same place of remove. It works perfectly fine. But when I try to remove a record, I am getting

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x288 in tid 29635
```

EDIT

After understanding that the remove has issue with RealmObjects having associations with other objects, I modified the code as follows, but still NO LUCK

```
val deletedDependent = realm.where(User::class.java)?.equalTo("id",deleteDependentData.dependentUUID)?.findFirst()
        info("Dependent id=>${deletedDependent?.id}")
        info("Dependent id=>${deletedDependent?.sessions}")

        info("Dependent id=>${deletedDependent?.secondaryCaregivers}")
        realm.executeTransaction {
            //deletedDependent?.removeFromRealm()

            val dependentSessions = deletedDependent?.sessions
            dependentSessions?.let {
                for(sess in dependentSessions) {
                    if(sess.temperature != null) {
                        sess?.temperature?.removeFromRealm()
                    }


                    if(sess.heart != null) {
                        sess?.heart?.removeFromRealm()
                    }


                    if(sess.lungs != null) {
                        sess?.lungs?.removeFromRealm()
                    }


                    sess?.removeFromRealm()

                }
            }

            deletedDependent?.sessions = null

            deletedDependent?.primaryCaregiver = null

            deletedDependent?.secondaryCaregivers = null

            deletedDependent?.removeFromRealm()

        }

Did someone face this issue and resolved it?
```

Here Session is another realm object.

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private User primaryCaregiver;
    private RealmList<User> secondaryCaregivers;
    @Required
    private String firstName;
    @Required
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private int gender;
    @Required
    private Date dob;
    private Double height;
    private Double weight;
    private Boolean isSelf;

    private Boolean isDeleted;
    private RealmList<Session> sessions;

    private int updateOrder;
```

Comment: What version of Realm are you using. I cannot seem to reproduce this?

Comment: @Christian Thanks Christian. I am using 0.87.0

Comment: Are you getting the error with the exact code above? Or does it only happen if you enable the lines you commented out?

Comment: @Christian Thanks again. Sorry its not the problem with removeFromRealm on RealmObject but a RealmObject with associations in it. I tried deleting a realm object without any relationships, worked fine. But not the object I am trying with. I will update my Q with the object details.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I updated the Q with my current code and realm object. Please let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks. Geetha